# How can i make my gnatt highcharts tooltip in this shape

Tags: charts, highcharts

code make the tooltip shape like this

[image: code make the tooltip shape like this]

this is what i tried but no luck

```
tooltip: {  
        outside: true,
        useHTML: true,
        style :{
          borderRadius: "10px 10px 10px"
        },
        pointFormatter: customPointFormatter
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the `useHTML` option and style the tooltip by CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip > span {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 0;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wver5hyf/

**About border radius:** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: this is not for gnatt highcharts

Comment: Hello @user15398154, Could describe in more details you what do you exactly mean?

Comment: i want the shape of the tooltip like stated above but in gnatt highcharts

Comment: It works in the same for gantt chart. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0tgvo1h3/